# Criar matriz 3x3 usando Imageviews - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, matriz

Como que eu faço para criar programaticamente uma matriz 3x3 composta de 9 ImageViews ?

Comment: Você já tentou simplesmente declará-la: `var anArray:[[ImageView]]` e para inicializar algo como `self.anArray = [[iv1, iv2, iv3], [iv4, iv5, iv6], [iv7, iv8, iv9]]`?

Comment: No fim das contas eu quero construir um quadrado com nove quadradinhos dentro. Cada quadradinho vai receber uma imagem que vai ter uma ordem específica. 

Como que eu faço com relação ao tamanho dessas imagens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comentário do @carlosfigueira responde sua pergunta:

```
var matriz: [[UIImageView]] = [[UIImageView(), UIImageView(), UIImageView()],
    [UIImageView(), UIImageView(), UIImageView()],
    [UIImageView(), UIImageView(), UIImageView()]]

matriz[1][1] //<UIImageView: 0x7fca39d34520; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fca39d33a70>>
```

Comment: Eu tenho 9 imagens no projeto e quero jogá-las nessa matriz, cada imagem vai ficar dentro de uma imageview, nessa mesma ordem de 1 a 9. 

Mas como q eu faço com relação ao tamanho dessas imagens ?

Comment: você pode usar o método de inicialização da classe `public init(frame: CGRect)`. No exemplo acima ficaria: `var matriz: [[UIImageView]] = [[UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)), UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)), ...`

Answer (score 0):

Já consideraste usar uma UICollectionView? A collection view se encarregaria de setar os frames das células onde as imagens aparecem, mesmo se as imagens possuem dimensões diferentes. Dá uma olhada no código abaixo, que cria uma array de 9 imagens e mostra como tu iria acessar esse array nos protocolos da collection view.

```
import UIKit
var arrayDeImagens = [UIImage]()
// só para criar as imagens fake
for _ in 1...9 {
    arrayDeImagens.append(UIImage())
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayDeImagens.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let imagem = arrayDeImagens[indexPath.item]

    /* aqui tu vais instanciar tua subclasse de UICollectionViewCell
       que contém uma UIImageView como subview e ira renderizar a tua imagem */

    return UICollectionViewCell() // essa linha é só para o compilador ficar quieto
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return arrayDeImagens[indexPath.item].size
}
```